# Get image size from base64 in C#

Tags: c#, image, base64

How to get **image size** from `base64` in C#?

Is it possible to do at all?

Comment: Depends entirely on what image format you're using. Please be more specific

Comment: @Rob It is PNG and JPG

Comment: @Gigabyte You can guess the answer, sure. But it'll just be a guess, which is a problem. From the original post, the following is unknown: Why does base64 matter? (The question may be how to read a base64 into an image format). What image format are you using? What do you mean by size? Dimensions? File size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not directly as it depends on what data/format is encoded in the Base64 string.
A rough approach would be (code not tested):

```
byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String("Your Base64 string here");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
{
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return new Tuple<int, int>(img.Width, img.Height); // or some other data container
}
```

Note: Image class comes from `System.Drawing`.
See also the [MSDN System.Drawing.Image class' documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: What makes you think this is Dimensions and not Size? OP should know to specify dimensions not size if that's what he was after.

Comment: @JeremyThompson You're right, I was a bit too fast there. Will update accordingly.